# VHDL integer to unsigned cast cost

Tags: vhdl

The code snippet below shows a two-step variable manipulation:

1) Convert an integer to an unsigned number

2) Cast an unsigned number to a std_logic_vector and extract a certain number of uppermost bits.

Could these two steps be consolidated into a single one?  That is, is this just typecasting (wire connections) or is some sort of clocked circuitry involved that could potentially result in a problem?

```
signal integrator_inter_uns :  unsigned(20 downto 0):= (others => '0'); 

...
...

counter : process(CLK)
begin
 if clk'event and clk = '1' then

   -- oveflow
    if pwm_counter = N then
        pwm_counter <= 0;

    -- 1
    elsif pwm_counter = 1 then      
        pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;

        integrator_inter_uns <= to_unsigned(integrator, integrator_inter_uns'length); -- 20 bit unsigned                            

    -- 2
    elsif pwm_counter = 2 then      
        pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;

        data <= std_logic_vector(integrator_inter_uns(15 downto 0));
    -- 3
    elsif pwm_counter = 3 then      
        pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;

        dac_input <= data;


else 
    pwm_counter  <= pwm_counter   + 1;

 end if;

end if;
end process;
```

Comment: This is not a minimal code example. If this is inside a standard process structure, the casts will be free, yes, but you're not always writing down to either integrator_inter_uns or data. Controlling the enables of your registers will cost circuitry.

Comment: @DonFusili The only purpose of the integrator_inter_uns  signal is to hold the value for the conversion steps.  If both steps can be done at the same time, the signal does not need to exist.

Comment: I understand that, both steps are just wires and can be done completely free, but the functionality will change if you do them together. It depends where this piece of code is found, until you provide a complete piece of code (I'd say at minimum your process), it's hard to judge.

Comment: I see.  The "data" signal is used at step 3.  This whole exercise is to minimize the pipeline delay to get the data out from the FPGA as soon as possible.  The question was edited.

Comment: Is this asynchronous by intention? You're not doing anything on the rising clock edge...

Comment: @Humpawumpa The state machine executes on the rising edge.  The state machine (pwm_counter) maximum is equal to the system update rate.

Comment: No it doesn't, you may need another `if` statement after the `if rising_edge()`

Comment: @Humpawumpa That was a typo in the question.  I cannot copy and paste code.  Fixed.

Comment: Okay, that looks better :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly perform two conversions in a single statement. They would synthesize to wires. **BUT** your code snippet has state-dependent behavior that would be lost if you combined the conversions. There's something going on with `pwm_counter` that you haven't told us about. If that state-dependent behavior is necessary then you will need a register to hold the intermediate value, `integrator_inter_uns`.

Comment: Elliot - I have modified the question.  The register is declared as a signal.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  dac_input <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integrator, integrator_inter_uns'length))(15 downto 0);
end if;
```

and implementing it won't "cost" anything, as long as you keep in mind that your data now arrives on the dac_input port two cycles earlier and that you will now see every change on the integrator signal/variable instead of every Nth change. (Or at least every value that was valid during your setup-hold time interval around each clk rising edge).

If you still only want every Nth clock cycle's value:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if pwm_counter = 1 then
    dac_input <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integrator, integrator_inter_uns'length))(15 downto 0);
  end if;

  if pwm_counter = N then
    pwm_counter := 0;
  else
    pwm_counter := pwm_counter+1;
  end if;
end if;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that your process is not reset, so the = N could fail in simulation since the pwm_counter is not going to be initialized.